# How to use long value in < iPhone5 and swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm parsing json object with Id (long) coming from a Java backend.
the id is declared as CLong in my app. On iPhones5 < it works, but on iPhone5 the id is invalid value.

Comment: if the id is more than 32 bits you won't be able to use it on iPhone 5 and less

Answer (score 1):

`CLong` is a `typedef` for `Int` in the iOS SDK:

```
/// The C 'long' type.
public typealias CLong = Int
```

From the [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> - On a 32-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int32.
> - On a 64-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int64.
>
> Unless you need to work with a specific size of integer, always use Int for integer values in your code. This aids code consistency and interoperability. Even on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many integer ranges.

If you need to keep your Integer size consistent across multiple architectures, use `Int32`.  If you value is larger than 32 bits, you should look into [handling overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199333/2415822).  Also consider sending a different data type rather than a long from your backend, such as a `String` or `NSNumber`.